# ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have installed BeautifulSoup using `easy_install` and I'm trying to run the following script:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))

print soup.prettify()
```

But I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\reading and writing xml file from web1.py", line 49, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

Comment: Did you set up `easy_install` to use Python2.7, or the inbuilt version of Python that came with whatever OS you're using? If you didn't specify 2.7, try doing Python2,4 or Python2.6

Comment: Looks like you installed BeautifulSoup for a different version of the Python than the one you're using to run this script.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...yea actually i need easy_install for 64 bit windows but i have installed 32 bit one. easy_install for 64 bit is not available here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files . what should i do then??

Answer (score 260):

Try this `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

This might be a problem with Beautiful Soup, version 4, and the beta days. I just read this from the homepage.

Comment: More than a year passed and nothing changed :)

Comment: For future users: as of May 2, 2014, this solution still works with Python 3.4.0 and BeautifulSoup 4.3.2 on Windows 8.1

Comment: Works for Windows10 as well :)

Comment: This solution is also working on Google Colab. The alternatives were problematic. Had to look around a bit before finding this.

Answer (score 22):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I installed it from apt-get and it worked fine:

`sudo apt-get install python-beautifulsoup`

Then just do:

`from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: The OP is using Windows (note the `C:\Python27` path in his traceback). This answer is useless for him.

Comment: @rmunn And what about all those Linux users (as me)? I've edited the answer. Thanks for the -1...

Answer (score 11):

Try This, Mine worked this way. To get any data of tag just replace the "a" with the tag you want.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib

url="http://currentaffairs.gktoday.in/month/current-affairs-january-2015"

soup = bs(urllib.urlopen(url))
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
        print link.string
```

Answer (score 6):

you can import bs4 instead of BeautifulSoup.
Since bs4 is a built-in module, no additional installation is required.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
       '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
       '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
       '</html>']
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc))

print soup.prettify()
```

If you want to request, using requests module.
request is using `urllib`, `requests` modules.
but I personally recommendation using `requests` module instead of `urllib`

module install for using:

```
$ pip install requests
```

Here's how to use the requests module:

```
import requests as rq
res = rq.get('http://www.example.com')

print(res.content)
print(res.status_code)
```

Comment: `bs4` is not a built-in module.

Answer (score 2):

First install beautiful soup version 4.
write command in the terminal window:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

then import the BeutifulSoup library

Comment: Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

if you got two version of python, maybe my situation could help you

this is my situation

1-> mac osx

2->  i have two version python , (1) system default version 2.7  (2) manually installed version 3.6

3-> i have install the beautifulsoup4 with `sudo pip install beautifulsoup4`

4-> i run the python file with `python3  /XXX/XX/XX.py`

so this situation 3 and 4 are the key part,  i have install beautifulsoup4 with "pip" but this module was installed for python verison 2.7,  and i run the python file with "python3".  so you should install beautifulsoup4 for the python 3.6;

with the `sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4` you can install the module for the python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with eclipse on windows 10.

I installed it like recommende over the windows command window (cmd) with:

```
C:\Users\NAMEOFUSER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\beautifulsoup4-4.8.2\setup.py install
```

BeautifulSoup was install like this in my python directory:

```
C:\Users\NAMEOFUSE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.8.2-py3.8.egg
```

After manually coping the bs4 and EGG-INFO folders into the site-packages folder everything started to work, also the example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
    <html>
        <body>
            <p> Ich bin ein Absatz!</p>
        </body>
    </html>
"""
print(html)


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find_all("p"))
```

Answer (score 0):

if you installed its this way(if you not, installing this way):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and if you used its this code(if you not, use this code):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

if you using windows system, check it if there are module, might saved different path its module

Answer (score 0):

**Don't forget to check this** - It could be due to multiple installed Python versions on your system, and the library is getting installed for different version, hence not accessible for the particular version that you are trying to use. I spent a lot of time stucking into this issue but none of the provided solutions worked.

Answer (score -1):

try this :
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Comment: This is just a partial copy of the top-voted answer without formatting or context. Please don't steal answers.