# import error due to bs4 vs BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, lxml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use `beautifulsoup` compatible `lxml` and it is giving me an error:

```
from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lxml/html/soupparser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from BeautifulSoup import \
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

I have `bs4` installed. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663980/importerror-no-module-named-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is caused by `soupparser.py` trying to import BeautifulSoup version 3 while you have version 4 installed. The module name was changed from `BeautifulSoup` to `bs4` in version 4.

You can trick `soupparser.py` into importing version 4 by mapping the `bs4` module to `BeautifulSoup` in [`sys.modules`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.modules) before importing `soupparser`:

```
import sys, bs4
sys.modules['BeautifulSoup'] = bs4

from lxml.html.soupparser import fromstring
```

Comment: Does soupparser work fine with bs4? If so, why does it still use an old version? Should we go and change soupparser to try importing bs4 as BeautifulSoup, and then only import BeautifulSoup if that fails? Assuming soupparser.py is available for modification in lxml's Github repo, making the change and eliminating this problem for future users should be trivial, right?

Comment: Soupparser is now ported to bs4. See separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a version of soupparser that works with bs4. It's available here: https://github.com/lxml/lxml/blob/master/src/lxml/html/soupparser.py

Answer (score -1):

Try adding :

`from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

and make sure you have the correct version of `BeautifulSoup` for your system installed.

Comment: I have beautifulsoup version 4 installed so from bs4 import BeautifulSoup works well but lxml.html.soupparser uses beautifulsoup 3 and has statement from BeautifulSoup import xyz.