# beautifulsoup4 doesn´t work

Tags: python, django

I´ve already installed `beautifulsoup4` but it doesn´t work.

This is the second time I try to install:

```
(k36) C:\GROWTHTECH\Projetos\blockchain>python -m pip install beautifulsoup4
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\patff\appdata\local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

When I made a test:

```
>>> import beautifulsoup4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'beautifulsoup4'
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'BeautifulSoup'
>>> exit()
```

Comment: have you tried `import bs4`?

Comment: Try this: https://python-forum.io/Thread-I-have-BeautifulSoup-instaled

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is BeautifulSoup4 hiding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902783/where-is-beautifulsoup4-hiding)

Answer (score 0):

The official import name of `BeautifulSoup` was changed to `bs4` in version 4 [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042023/import-error-due-to-bs4-vs-beautifulsoup) [[2]](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). If it is installed correctly otherwise, import the package by calling:

```
import bs4
```

Comment: yes, but it didn´t work also. >>> import bs4  File "C:\Users\patff\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\k36\lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3.6.egg\bs4\__init__.py", line 53
    'You are trying to run the Python 2 version of Beautiful Soup under Python 3. This will not work.'<>'You need to convert the code, either by installing it (`python setup.py install`) or by running 2to3 (`2to3 -w bs4`).'

Comment: @Patricia on the plus side though, it looks like it gave you the solution to your problem!