# "ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup" error even after installation

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup, failed-installation

I'm running into the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\files\samplefileoutput.py", line 1, in <module>
    import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup
```

when I try to run the following file:

```
import BeautifulSoup
f = open('c:\output.txt', 'a')
f.write('Hello World!\n')
f.close()
```

I thought my installation was successful.  I am using a Windows 7 PC.  I extracted the source tarball and then through the command line, typed "setup.py install" once I had changed the directory to the extracted BeautifulSoup folder.  There didn't appear to be an error message during the install.  It finished with this line:

```
Writing C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2-py2.7.egg-info
```

Can anyone please provide some guidance?  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663980/importerror-no-module-named-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Beautiful Soup 4's module is `bs4`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

will work, or

```
import bs4
```

if you want to import the entire module.

Comment: Do I type this in the command line or shell?  What does this instruction do?  Thx!

Comment: @JerryCarson: Replace the `import BeautifulSoup` (in your script) with `import bs4` (if I recall correctly). Or you may want to install an earlier version of Beautiful Soup (before v4).

Comment: This really worked worked from, it was included setup.py with  `easy_install`  and `eggs` which is obselete now. so independently installing this python module worked this way..

Answer (score 0):

Simply run:

```
    pip install BeautifulSoup
```