# No module named BeautifulSoup (but it should be installed)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I downloaded BeautifulSoup.
Then I upgraded pip:

> pip install --upgrade pip

Then, installed BS:

> pip install beautifulsoup4

It seems like everything worked fine, but now when I run these three lines of code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import csv
```

I get this error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File
>   "C:\Users\rshuell001.spyder2\temp.py", line 1, in 
>       from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup

I'm using Anaconda-Spyder

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/12902800/284795

Comment: This did the trick:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663980/importerror-no-module-named-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it should be: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.